# How can we give a color with specific color code in the styles.xml in Android Studio?

Tags: android, css, colors

I want to change the status bar color to a specific color with a color code. Only the default colors can be specified in the code as given below, is there any way to give a specific color code to get that color?

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark_blue_Shade1</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

create a color.xml into values folder

code for `color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <color name="dark_blue_Shade1">#000080</color>
</resources>
```

if the `color.xml` already exists there then just put the

```
<color name="dark_blue_Shade1">#000080</color>
```

inside `<resources>   </resources>`  tag

Comment: Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

create color.xml file inside values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ColorPrimary">#8E67E0</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#59419B</color>
    <color name="LightPrimaryColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</color>
    <color name="AccentColor">#ff4081</color>
    <color name="PrimaryText">#212121</color>
    <color name="SecondarText">#727272</color>
</resources>
```

and then in style.xml file change like this

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/AccentColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

From this your entire project will take this colors.

> ColorPrimaryDark

is your status bar color you dont want to apply it manually system will get colorPrimaryDark as your status bar color